# How to refactor multiple extensions with different Func parameters with same result

Tags: c#, lambda, func

I am new to Func/Action/Predicate and want to know what is the best way to refactor my code as I will potentially have a lot of repeated code.

I have created 2 extension methods which take a Func parameter (always returning bool):

```
public static void MyExtension<T>(this T obj, Func<T, bool> predicate)
    {
        do
        {
            //function code
        } while (predicate(obj));
    }
    public static void MyExtension<T1, T2>(this T1 obj, T2 OtherObject, Func<T1, T2, bool> predicate)
    {
        do
        {
            //function code
        } while (predicate(obj, OtherObject));
    }
```

What I want, is to only code the do/while loop once as I might have a lot of functions which will only generate a different Func but will all want to run the same do/while loop.

I was thinking something like this, which takes any Func parameter and runs it on each loop. The code in the loop doesn't care about the types passed into the Func.

```
public static void DoLoop(Func predicate)
    {
        do
        {
            //function code
        } while (predicate);
    }
```

But this clearly doesnt work. Does anyone know how to resolve this, or am I doing something fundamentally wrong?

The end result is I want to call the code like below:

```
        var Obj = new MyObj();
        Obj.MyExtension((x) => x.Prop1.Contains("string"));

        var OtherObj = new MyObj();
        Obj.MyExtension(OtherObj, (x,y) => x.Prop1.Contains("string") && y.Prop1.Contains("other"));
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your generic methods are parameterized on a different number of generic types, you need to keep all function signatures in place in order for the calling code to compile. However, you can move the implementation into a common helper method to reduce repeated code:

```
// This is your single implementation
private static void DoLoop(Func<bool> predicate) {
    do {
        //function code
    } while (predicate());
}
// These are the wrappers
public static void MyExtension<T>(this T obj, Func<T, bool> predicate) {
     DoLoop(() => predicate(obj));
}
public static void MyExtension<T1, T2>(this T1 obj, T2 OtherObject, Func<T1, T2, bool> predicate) {
     DoLoop(() => predicate(obj, OtherObject));
}
```

Wrappers construct parameter-less predicate, and pass it to the private `DoLoop` method, which provides the implementation.

Comment: perfect! thanks. slight change needed to get it to work. Need to change } while (predicate); to } while (predicate());